# Different output in Python shell and python argument (xx.py)

Tags: python, linux, installation, conda

My python interpreter is:

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ which python
/home/markd/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I installed UMAP by `conda install -c conda-forge umap-learn`, then in Python shell it works well, e.g.

```py
(base) ➜  ~ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import umap
>>> print(umap.__version__)
0.3.10
```

However if I run `python testumap.py` or `python -u testumap.py` it failed:

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ cat testumap.py
import umap
print(umap.__version__)
(base) ➜  ~ python testumap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testumap.py", line 1, in <module>
    import umap
  File "testumap.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(umap.__version__)
AttributeError: module 'umap' has no attribute '__version__'
```

I don't know what's wrong. Is this because of Conda or UMAP?

I've tried to import and print version of other installed libraries and they show the same output in Python shell or python argument (python xxx.py).

Comment: Define the the path in python file at first.
`#!bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` 

Check this as well - https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/

Comment: I've tried both, and `#!/home/markd/anaconda3/bin/python` but problem still exists

Comment: Try this - 
`import umap.umap_ as umap`
If not work - then 
Also try to do a clean install `umap-learn`, instead of `umap`

Comment: Okay thx. I know why... stupid me.. I renamed the python file to `umap.py` and I forgot all about that... Thanks you